# fibered knots in $ S^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Given a fibered knot $k$ in $S^3$, we have the decomposition of $S^3$ as union of $M$ and $S^1\times D^2 $, where M is a fiber bundle over $S^1$, with fiber $F$ such that its boundary is the knot $k$. We also have decomposition of $S^3$ as two copies of $S^1\times D^2$. Does this mean that M is actually diffeomorphic to $S^1\times D^2$?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 4):

No. A theorem of Gordon and Luecke states that knots are determined by the homeomorphism type of their complement. Therefore, $M$ is only equal to $S^1\times D^2$ for the trivial knot.

Comment: I should point out that in this context one does not need the full strength of Gordon-Luecke's theorem: a much easier proof of the statement "$S^3-K\cong S^1\times D^2 \implies K$ is trivial" can be given using the loop theorem. If I'm not mistaken a proof is in Lickorish's book.

Comment: @GiulioBelletti: indeed. Actually, to answer the OP, one really only needs to exhibit a single fibered knot with knot group not equal to $\mathbb Z$!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the knot complement $M$. Then a homeomorphism $M \cong S^1 \times D^2$ induces an isomorphism on fundamentalgroups, hence $\pi_1(M) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. But this contradicts to the early pages of every knot theory book, where it is stated that only the unknot has this trivial group.